# How can I customize the unobtrusive validation in ASP.NET MVC 3 to match my style?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

The default validation in MVC 3 is based on [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), which I can usually customize with something like:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
  submitHandler: function() { alert('submitHandler'); },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    // do something important here
    alert('errorPlacement');
  },
  errorClass: "error",
  errorElement: "input",
  onkeyup: false,
  onclick: false
})
```

But, that doesn't seem to work in MVC 3. Specifically, errorPlacement doesn't ever seem to be called and I've no idea why. I'll get the submitHandler called, but never errorPlacement.

How can I customize the validation to match whatever structure/style that I require for my site's style? The default is great, but it doesn't always work in every situation.

Answer (score 47):

In my code instead of using `$.validator.setDefaults` I access the form validator using `$("#form_selector").data('validator')` and then change the settings.

```
$(function () {

    var validator = $("#form_selector").data('validator');
    validator.settings.errorPlacement = function(error,element) {
        alert('errorPlacement');
    };

});
```

See if it works for you.

Comment: Worked great, thanks! Was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why the mvc3 version of validation doesnt understand customisations like the normal jquery validation.

Comment: This works, except I also need to set things like errorClass, errorElement, etc. Any suggestions there?

Comment: Where do you call $("#form_selector").data('validator') ?? When I do this no property is returned.

Comment: Just a note that this no longer works, as of jquery.unobtrusive 3.2.6 ... This should not be wrapped in a jQuery function. Anton's answer seems to be the most correct today.

Answer (score 40):

I had the same issue, but realized that the Unobtrusive plugin was actually *casuing* the issue, it will override any options you set!  The trick is to have your code written/included in the following order:

1. The validate plugin
2. Your custom code & options
3. The unobtrusive plugin

**Any other order and this won't be set correctly!**

Comment: Thank you. By far the easiest and most elegant solution.

Comment: http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41201-asp-net-mvc/suggestions/3583148-update-jquery-validate-unobtrusive-implementation-

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer?! I've battled with this for months and months on various legacy projects and came across this by chance. It makes so much sense now. Thank you.

Comment: This unobtrusive will wipe your options out, so use the accepted solution.  Don't know if this is a change in the last 5 years, so may have worked previously

Answer (score 10):

Right way to do this:

**Script order:**

1. The validate plugin
2. The unobtrusive plugin
3. Your custom code&options

**Custom code&options script:**

```
var settings = {
   //...
}; 

// override jQuery unobtrusive validator settings
$.validator.unobtrusive.options = settings;
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, this is the right way to do it, when you need to **overwrite** these settings: `errorClass`, `errorElement` and want to **extend** these functions: `errorPlacement`, `invalidHandler` and `success`. For all the other options you should use the solution presented by @ChrisBarr

Comment: This is the correct way to do this now with MVC 5 and Bootstrap 4 and JQuery 3.3.1

Answer (score 1):

I use this code for my Custom Settings:

```js
    const validationCustomSettings = {
        validClass: "is-valid",
        errorClass: "is-invalid",
    };
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults(validationCustomSettings);
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.options = validationCustomSettings;
```

Answer (score -3):

All I did for this just duplicated my style to match for the elements that Unobtrusive validator adds.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "field-error" })
```

When validation error occurs "ValidationMessageFor" adds a class "field-validation-error" like below.

```
<span class="field-error field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="EmailAddress" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span for="EmailAddress" generated="true" class="">Email address is Required.</span></span>
```

So i duplicated my style like

```
.field-error.***field-validation-error*** {position:relative;color:#fff;background:#589BC9;}
```

I thought this is the simple way to fix this.