# Custom MVC validation attribute and bootstrap format issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap

I am using ASP.net MVC with twitter bootstrap.

I have added the following to get the fields with errors to style properly in bootstrap

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest(".control-group").addClass("error");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest(".control-group").removeClass("error");
    }
});
```

This works great with all validation except custom validations attributes. The custom validator I created checks to see if a checkbox is checked, if not it expects something to be entered in a text field. This is just one example, but other custom validation attributes I have created fail in the same way described below.

If I submit the form, all errors are styled appropriately except for the field with my custom validator. However I know the validator ran because error message showed up, but the message and field are black instead of red.

If I enter some text in the field to satisfy the validator, the error message goes away. Then if I remove that text, the error message returns and everything is styled red as it should be.

Then, if I submit the form again, the red styling goes away even though the error remains, but only for the field with the custom validator, all other error remain red.

On form submit, the defaults I set(shown above) aren't run for the field with the custom validator, but the defaults are run for everything else.

Yet, with the on blur and key up events on the field with the custom validator, everything behaves as expected and all styling works as expected.

I am at a loss of what to look at next. Any help/direction is appreciated.

Comment: Can you recreate your example in one of the sites http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/ for a better view of the error?

Thank you

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493512/jquery-unobtrusive-validation-in-net-mvc-3-showing-success-checkmark

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently until I found out that I had valid and invalid inputs within the same `.control-group`. (`<input type="hidden">` fields in my case). If that applies to your case as well, you can use the `errorClass` provided by the `highlight` and `unhighlight` methods like this:

```
function highlight(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element)
        .addClass(errorClass)
        .closest(".control-group")
        .addClass("error");
};

function unhighlight(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    var c = $(element)
        .removeClass(errorClass)
        .closest(".control-group");
    // make sure not to remove parent container error class, 
    //if there is still an invalid input field inside
    if (c.find("." + errorClass).length < 1) 
        c.removeClass("error");
};
```