# MVC3 Force Validation of Hidden Fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I need to enable the validation of hidden fields using ASP.net MVC3 unobtrusive validation.

The reason behind this is a jquery plugin which hides the original input field to show something fancier. But this disables validation of the field as it becomes hidden.

I tried to use the following code but without success.

```
$("form").validate({
    ignore: ""
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With a hint from [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487139/how-can-i-customize-the-unobtrusive-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3-to-match-my-styl) I was able to manipulate the options of the unobtrusive validator object.

```
var validator = $("#myFormId").data('validator');
validator.settings.ignore = "";
```

Comment: Nice work this has been driving me nuts for a very long time :-)

Comment: Awesome!!!. I was looking for an answer. Hmm I need to start looking more into inner workings for MVC3 unobtrusive plugin.