# Remote attribute validation on blur in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes

The build in remote attribute in asp.net mvc 3 does the validation "onchange".
I want it to validate on blur, is there a way to custom it? or there is something else for doing so? I'm sure it's a very common need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Remote Validation only on blur?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407652/asp-net-remote-validation-only-on-blur)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Remote Validation only on blur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407652/asp-net-remote-validation-only-on-blur)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could [set default values](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/setDefaults) like this and disable validation when a key is pressed:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ onkeyup: false });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please explain me what that line of code does? I didn't see any explantion in the line you wrote. Thanks again!

Comment: @gdoron, as the documentation explains, the `setDefaults` method allows you to override default configuration values for the jquery validate plugin. Setting `oneyup` to false indicates that validation should not be performed when the user releases a key.

Comment: Is there any different between the code you wrote and the code below written by offbysome?

Comment: @gdoron, yes there is. When you use the `setDefaults` method you are explicitly setting default values for all validation plugins on the current page. With the code below you are attaching the `validate` plugin additionally and thus conflicting with the ASP.NET MVC 3 unobtrusive validator plugin.

Comment: In a different page I need to disable the onkeyup for only one property. How can I do that

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using [jQuery validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) and not MS Ajax Validation in ASP.NET MVC 3, you would turn off onchange validation (technically its onKeyUp validation) by using this:

```
$(".selector").validate({
   onkeyup: false
});
```