# Remote Attribute Validation only on blur

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, data-annotations, onblur

I am new to ASP.Net MVC and I am trying to learn it through a sample project from scratch without scaffolding. I am using MVC 5 with EF6. I am trying to understand the Remote attribute in the System.Web.Mvc namespace. I understand that it does validation to see if an entity (like username) already exists or not, before letting the user create one and returns a JSON response. But it fires off on every key press and I have already searched and found some solutions (link below), which refer to turning off the validations in jQuery (since it's client side) for every key press and use it on blur. (I know people have already asked this question before.Sorry for repeating, but I didn't get a good solution.) But this will do it for every control. I wanted more granular control (something like an option / switch on the attribute, which will help me control this). Can anyone please suggest?

[Remote attribute validation on blur in asp.net mvc 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137651/remote-attribute-validation-on-blur-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

[ASP.NET Remote Validation only on blur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407652/asp-net-remote-validation-only-on-blur)

Also, these options are for MVC 3. So, I was wondering, if there are any better solutions in MVC 5.