# How to hook into the MVC Jquery validation?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'd like to be able to take actions before JQUery MVC tries validate my form, then after and if it has been validated I'd like to do a few more things.

I currently do this:

```
    this.form.bind('submit', function (evt) {

        <some code>

        if (!this.form.valid()) {
            return;
        }

        <some code>
    }.bind(this));
```

But obviously the validation already occurs once before this is even fired (and I'd like to avoid that since there are things it should not validate due to some specific conditions).

Comment: I'd suggest you wrap up the validation in a function then trigger it when necessary.

Comment: function revalidation(){<validation code>}; then call it when necessary, well you'd better post your validation code here so I can answer better.

Comment: What's <validation code>? I didn't write any of it. It's all handled by MVC.

Comment: Oh, thought you were using jQuery.validation library ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165763/adding-delay-to-remote-validation-attribute-mvc3 this may help you